# A word describing the core point of a newspaper opinion column

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Is there a word that denotes or describes the most important point in the newspaper opinion section?

For instance, have a look at the screenshot of the piece of opinion [from DAWN](https://epaper.dawn.com/?page=27_10_2018_009):

[image: Screenshot]

In the picture above, I have **enclosed** the bold and enlarged point of the opinion written by A.G Noorani; while the word which I am requesting here, can have something to do with graphic design, because it's all about the design of the opinion column. So how do you describe such points in terms of graphic design?

I, by researching and asking question, could get a single word describing such point: **core point**. Can I describe it as a core point? Or are there other better alternatives to it?

Comment: What's wrong with word **"core"**?

Comment: http://www.warrencountyschools.org/userfiles/2607/8th_Grade_Determining_Central_Ideas_&_Analyzing_Development.pdf

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/crux

Comment: (But I would tend to use "theme".)

Comment: There is a specific term for the way you handled it as far as layout goes - [pull quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote). But it sounds like you want a term for the content of such a box.

Comment: Too much ambiguity in question.

Comment: Those kinds of things are not *always* core to an article's main point, and use of them is not limited to opinion pieces. They are often exact quotes from the article, not summaries. This particular one seems to be a paraphrase, replacing "book banning" in the article with "censorship".

Comment: This question is not properly posed. It was not clear that this was a question about layout lingo.

Comment: Did you consider *gist*?

Comment: Now, I get it. The title seems to be asking one thing while the body another. … ***A word describing the core point*** *of a newspaper opinion column…* is asking for the synonym of "core" whereas you are asking what the typographic detail , the enlarged quote, is called in graphics (or typography, whatever). No wonder you got answers such as "essence" and "crux". Next time, make sure the title and the body question do not conflict with each other.

Comment: I made the mistake of voting to reopen this question, despite several attempts, I can't retract that vote. Apologies to all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In terms of graphic design, the text framed in red is called a [*pull quote*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_quote), a common technique to break up large areas of text that also functions as a secondary headline to attract the reader to an article.

The relationship of the highlighted text to the article depends on who wrote it, which in most publications would not be the author of the article itself.

In this case, with only a single pull quote, it functions as an explanatory or summary subtitle:

> Banning Books: A new form of censorship has emerged …

Comment: I don't think the question is about graphic design.

Comment: If it's about the text in the red box, it's about a pull quote.

Comment: A pull quote can be anything. It does not have to be the "core point" of the article, as stated in the question. In fact, it will usually be the most interesting - or even better, sensational - sentence in the content. Extra points if taken out of context for shock value.

Answer (score 7):

"A new form of censorship has emerged", is the **essence** of this article

> "The essence of something is its basic and most important characteristic which gives it its individual identity."   [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/essence)
>
> "The most important part or aspect of something: The essence of her argument is that the policy is wrongheaded."  [**TFD**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/essence)

Answer (score 4):

Two words seem appropriate to me:

> crux /krəks,kro͝oks/Submit noun the decisive or most important point
>   at issue. "the crux of the matter is that attitudes have changed"
>   synonyms: nub, heart, essence, central point, main point, core,
>   center, nucleus, kernel; informalbottom line "with whom John will be
>   living is the crux of the situation"

and

> the·sis /ˈTHēsis/Submit noun
>   1. a statement or theory that is put forward as a premise to be maintained or proved. "his central thesis is that psychological life
>   is not part of the material world" synonyms:  theory, contention,
>   argument, line of argument, proposal, proposition, idea, claim,
>   premise, assumption, hypothesis, postulation, supposition "the central
>   thesis of his lecture"

Comment: "Thesis" is the answer that immediately occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

The "***message***", perhaps - The broad meaning of something; an expressed or implied central theme or significant point, esp. one with political, social, or moral importance; frequently in to get one's message across. (OED)

Or, the "***nub***" - The heart of a matter; the crux or central point of a discussion, argument. (OED)

Answer (score 1):

Newspaper editorials have **a main argument** in expressing a point of view.

Read about that here: **[main argument](https://pro-essay-writer.com/blog/editorial-essay)**

Core argument is fine but it's not a traditional term in editorial writing and is an overused word.

Answer (score 1):

The quote is the [**premise**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/premise) of the article.

OED:

> 1.1 An assertion or proposition which forms the basis for a work or theory.
>
> ‘the fundamental premise of the report’

Answer (score 1):

A short blurb that expresses the main point is a [summary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/summary).  If it’s a single line from the piece itself, it’s a thesis statement.  If it’s a condensed version of the piece rather than a direct quote, it’s a synopsis.  If it’s about a paragraph long and precedes the full text, it’s an abstract.  Longer than that, an executive summary.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *lede.*

[Oxford Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lede) defines it:

> The opening sentence or paragraph of a news article, summarizing the most important aspects of the story.

Sometimes a news story will be written without an opening summary, so there won't be a lede. But often the lede will be the most important idea in the story.

The pull quote in the example you show is not the lede.

Answer (score 0):

The core point is often referred to as the *thrust* of the article. *Thesis* also works, and is more formal. *Premise* is not as good, because it describes the start of the discussion, not what follows. The premise of the article is that book burning is bad and that book banning is akin to book burning.